# Create Line chart x axis datetime and y axis temprature

Tags: c#, asp.net, charts

I am having SQL table "Reading" where i have datetime and recorded temperature at that instance.
I am trying to plot the Line chart with x axis as Datetime and at y axis there is temperature. I am doing it in asp.net c#.
Now the datetime instances are random.
I tried few examples but did not had a luck.
Please help.

```
try
        {
            if (con.State != ConnectionState.Open) con.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select ReadingInstance,Temprature from Readings", con);

            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            da.Fill(ds);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
        }
        finally
        {
            if (con.State != ConnectionState.Closed) con.Close();
        }

        if (ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            Chart1.BorderSkin.SkinStyle = BorderSkinStyle.Emboss;
            Chart1.BorderlineColor = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(26, 59, 105);
            Chart1.BorderlineWidth = 3;
            Chart1.BackColor = Color.NavajoWhite;

            Chart1.ChartAreas.Add("chtArea");
            Chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Title = "Category Name";
            Chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.TitleFont = new System.Drawing.Font("Verdana", 11, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Bold);
            Chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.Title = "UnitPrice";
            Chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.TitleFont = new System.Drawing.Font("Verdana", 11, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Bold);
            Chart1.ChartAreas[0].BorderDashStyle = ChartDashStyle.Solid;
            Chart1.ChartAreas[0].BorderWidth = 2;
            //Chart1.ChartAreas[0].Area3DStyle.Enable3D = true;
            //Chart1.ChartAreas[0].Area3DStyle.Inclination = 45;
            //Chart1.ChartAreas[0].Area3DStyle.Rotation = 45;
            //Chart1.ChartAreas[0].Area3DStyle.PointDepth = 100;
            //Chart1.ChartAreas[0].Area3DStyle.PointGapDepth = 1;

            Chart1.Legends.Add("Temprature");
            Chart1.Series.Add("Temprature");
            //Chart1.Series[0].Palette = ChartColorPalette.Bright;
            Chart1.Series[0].ChartType = System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting.SeriesChartType.Line;
            Chart1.Series[0].Points.DataBindXY(ds.Tables[0].DefaultView, "ReadingInstance", ds.Tables[0].DefaultView, "Temprature");

            //Chart1.Series[0].IsVisibleInLegend = true;
            Chart1.Series[0].IsValueShownAsLabel = true;
            Chart1.Series[0].ToolTip = "Data Point Y Value: #VALY{G}";

            // Setting Line Width
            Chart1.Series[0].BorderWidth = 3;
            Chart1.Series[0].Color = Color.Red;

            // Setting Line Shadow
            //Chart1.Series[0].ShadowOffset = 5;

            //Legend Properties
            Chart1.Legends[0].LegendStyle = LegendStyle.Table;
            Chart1.Legends[0].TableStyle = LegendTableStyle.Wide;
            Chart1.Legends[0].Docking = Docking.Bottom;
        }
```

In aspx.cs and

```
<asp:Chart ID="Chart1" runat="server" Width="700px" Height="500px"></asp:Chart>
```

in .aspx

Comment: Why are DateTimes random if you're selecting them from your database? Can you share the code you've tried? I assume you're doing something like SELECT Temp_Date, Temp_Temp from MyTemps ?

Comment: Shared the code. Actually the readings are not getting received at particular instance. So they are random time interval between them. Also it has readings from multiple devices.

Comment: Your dataset code looks wonky. Are you sure you're getting a populated table out of that? You're calling fill(DataSet) without instantiating a DataSet

Comment: table just have ReadingInstance, Temprature and Device ID columns. I tried with select * as well as many combinations but still chart is not showing..

Comment: Yes, but you need to create a DataSet before filling it. string queryString = 
  "SELECT CustomerID, CompanyName FROM dbo.Customers";
SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(queryString, connection);

**DataSet customers = new DataSet();**
adapter.Fill(customers, "Customers");
Are you sure you're getting data?

Comment: Yes with the Query I shown, I am getting data in dataset.

Comment: Besides my code is there any way I can achieve it?? Since I just need to show Temperature readings at various times.

Comment: Take it out to the minimal and when it works, start optimizing. List<DateTime> sampleDates = new List<DateTime>();List<double> temps = new List<double>;foreach (DataRow pRow in da.Tables["{TheNameofYourDataSet}"].Rows){sampleDates.Add(pRow["ReadingInstance"];temps.Add(pRow["Temprature"];} Step1: make sure sampleDates and temps both have Count >0 and the same Count. Step 2:Then add sampleDates.ToArray() to pointsX and temps.ToArray() to points.Y -- for(int I=0;i<sampleDate.Count;i++){Chart[0].Series[0].Points.AddXY(sampleDates[I],temps[I]);}

Comment: PS - propery spelled in "temperature," not "Temprature" - could be a problem when connecting to database?